# Successfully Removed access token and refresh token using a LogoutSuccessHandler, now on new request for fresh token does not ask a login page again

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

On logout I remove access token and refresh token using a LogoutSuccessHandler  but when I try to call for authorization again it just gives me token instead of launching login page again what should I be done here to force user to show login page only.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2RefreshToken;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class CustomLogoutSuccessHandler
extends AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler
implements LogoutSuccessHandler{
    private static final String BEARER_AUTHENTICATION = "Bearer ";
    private static final String HEADER_AUTHORIZATION = "authorization";

    public CustomLogoutSuccessHandler(TokenStore tokenStore) {
        this.tokenStore=tokenStore;
    }
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

         String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_AUTHORIZATION);
            if (token != null && token.startsWith(BEARER_AUTHENTICATION)) {
                OAuth2AccessToken oAuth2AccessToken = tokenStore.readAccessToken(token.replace(BEARER_AUTHENTICATION, "").trim());
                if (oAuth2AccessToken != null) {
                    OAuth2RefreshToken oAuth2RefreshToken = oAuth2AccessToken.getRefreshToken();
                    if (oAuth2RefreshToken != null)
                        tokenStore.removeRefreshToken(oAuth2RefreshToken);
                    tokenStore.removeAccessToken(oAuth2AccessToken);
                }
            }
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    }

}
```

Following is configuration I have given for httpSecurity.

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().permitAll().and().csrf().disable();
             http.logout().
             clearAuthentication(true).
             deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").
             logoutSuccessHandler(new CustomLogoutSuccessHandler(tokenStore())).
             logoutSuccessUrl("/login").
             invalidateHttpSession(true);
    }
```

Comment: well, but you use it with some oauth 2 provider like for example facebook? Then you do not want and dont do logout on facebook itself. When user logs in again in your app it underneath check with fb if user is logged in. Then spring just pass him through.

Comment: I have written oauth2 provider using spring and authenticated from there only, not using facebook oauth.On logout action both tokens gets deleted from jdbcTokenStore.